# using an exists statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement, crash, progress-bar

I have made a progress bar using the winProgressBar method in R. What I want to do is if someone instantiates my program while it is doing all of its processing, I want the current progress bar to close. I tried using a statement that says

```
if(exists(progressBar)) {
  close(progressBar);
}
```

but I get an error from the console that says

```
Error in exists(progressBar) : object 'progressBar' not found
```

I know that it will not exist during the first iteration of my program, but there is no reason that I can find that would make an if statement cause the program to crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the help for `exists` you will see the following under Arguments

> x  a variable name (given as a character string).

So

```
exists('progressBar')
```

will return TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: +1. Not knowing `exists` exists, I would have tried `"progressBar" %in% ls()`